# how to know the completion of of data transfer in server

Tags: c

i want to make the server  aware of completion of data transfer to the client and wait to see whether client is making any new request or not (at same port).

like conversation:
CLIENT: hi   //here i would like to tell the server that the client has sent the data and waiting for response and later again it can send to server
SERVER: hi
CLIENT: how are you?
SERVER: I am fine, thanks!
SERVER: What about you?
CLIENT: I am fine as well, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three ways of telling that the client is done.

1. The client sends a special message that means "I'm done, close my connection.", whereby the server closes the connection.
2. The client simply closes the connection, and the server has to handle it when it detects it.
3. For protocols that are of the type request-response, like a web browser and server, then the server simply closes the connection after it sends the response to the client.

Comment: @1 if server closes then client could not send a new request at same port.@2 also same but @3 i think it might help me...thnks alot

Comment: @Subratnayak The client can always reconnect if it wants to send more data after the connection has been closed.

Answer (score 0):

There are two kinds of solutions for this type of problem:

- Each message contains a length in the header so the other side knows how many bytes of data to expect. If you don't know the length in advance, send the data in chunks.
- Each message is terminated with a special symbol that can't appear anywhere else

This is independent of one side terminating the connection because the other side then gets an error when they try to read/send data and you need to handle this error in any case.